# How does the comparator in the NE555 compare its two inputs?

Tags: comparator, 555

[image: Internal schematic of bipolar NE555]

This is a circuit diagram from the very detailed and helpful [NE555 Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC). The yellow and red coloured segments are comparators, comparing Thresh and Trig to fractions of Vcc. If I know how a comparator works, I understand the circuit and I'm happy. I have stared at the yellow part for too long! I can't seem to understand why it works.

The red and yellow parts are not symmetric in their inputs, which tells me there is something to be seen there. I don't see it! From what I understand, most of these are depletion mode. By the way, the bold line under the third BJT starting from top left going right is Gnd. The output of the comparator is the line from the Thres side of the circuit into the purple flip flop part.

When 2V_cc/3 < Thres, the comparator goes LOW. What is the causal chain of clearly connected events which drives the output to low after this (given that the initial state was HIGH, i.e. Thres > 2V_cc/3)?

Comment: Did you read this https://cdn.evilmadscientist.com/KitInstrux/555/555_principles_rev30.pdf and this http://www.righto.com/2016/02/555-timer-teardown-inside-worlds-most.html

Comment: Looking at the circuit of a 555 is not a good place to begin understanding a comparator. Start simpler; understand first why a single CE transistor has a voltage gain that is bigger when the emitter resistance is smaller. It all starts from that point. Do you understand that idea?

Comment: You don't have depletion mode in a BJT.

Comment: This detailed schematic is for those who understand Integrated Circuits (ICs). In addition to the links above, you might want to read the free ebook **written by the designer of the NE555**, you can find that on this site: http://www.designinganalogchips.com/  The Ebook discusses basic (on-chip) circuits.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everybody. I will have a look at the links and consolidate a firmer understanding of more basic aspects.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh wow, I didn't know Camenzind wrote a book! Thank you for indirectly showing this to me, this promises to be fascinating.